# What is inside a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities, neutron-stars

I'm trying to understand what causes a black hole in terms of it's composition.
We know a start can die and collapse into a neutron star, but if the neutro star is not dense enough to create a black hole, then what it is inside?
I mean, what is more dense than a neutrons glued together? 
Is a "quarks" star? are the neutrons destroyed and all the quarks inside put together?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127179/25301

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401668/2451 and links therein.

Comment: maybe duplicate yes, but was not answered. I mean what could cause in terms of particles a black hole? if neutrons create a neutron star, and quarks create a quark star, how can create a black hole? what is more dense than quarks glued together?